# how to change sound card in android applicatio

Tags: android

We have custom ALLWINNER A20 board with android. We compiled android source code and booted successfully.
We have 2 sound card 1.HDMI 2.ANALOG codec both are working fine.

In ubuntu there is an option to pass sound card number in mplayer and aplay like.
mplayer -ao alsa:device=hw=0.0 filename
mplayer -ao alsa:device=hw=1.0 filename

Now we want to develop and android apk which will play songs only in HDMI sound card and another apk only
through Analog sound card or Is there anyway to pass sound card number as an argument in android.

Kindly give me any hints or link to achieve this.

Regards
Aakash